# Derive a cost production function give prod f, only K

Tags: mathematical-economics, cobb-douglas

In this question, only K is included and L is excluded how would I go about deriving it?[image]

Total cost= Fixed costs + Average costs.

Since the variable input costs r per unit, the variable costs is r times the number of units rQ, hence $VC= rK^\alpha$.

Thus $C(Q)= c_0 + rK^\alpha$

Is the above solution correct? 
IS there a more mathematical way of doing it, one that involves grpahs etc.

Comment: Please show your work thus far or this is likely to be closed.

Comment: Last time I checked, univariate problems were easier to solve than multivariate...

Comment: If both K and L were present, it would have been much easier to derive it, however with L not being part of the production function, it gets a bit tricky!

Answer (score 2):

Here you have to express $K$ in terms of $Q$, since the cost depends on the number of units of capital employed and not on the number of products produced. You have
\begin{equation}
Q = K^a \Leftrightarrow K = Q^{\frac{1}{a}}
\end{equation}
so your cost function will be
\begin{equation}
C(Q) = c_0 + rK(Q) = c_0 + rQ^{\frac{1}{a}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Great thanks, sometime I complicate things for myself!

Comment: What would the 1st derivative of that be? (i.e MC)

Comment: Easy, it would just be MC = (r/a)*Q^((1-a)/a)

Comment: perfect thanks, now how would you interpret that in an economic context? Thanks a mill for your help!

Comment: @blzox it seems like you're expecting him to solve the whole problem set? Be cautious with the number and type of followup-questions you pose in comments to someone who already answered your initial question.

Comment: Haha yeah I agree, looks too much like these are questions (b) and (c) from the same problem. The last question is too philosophical anyways, good luck with it!